# language kleene star union not equal to union of language kleene star

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

Find languages A and B such that $A^* \cup B^* \neq (A \cup B)^*$.

Is this even possible?

I tried:

$A:\{$ $\epsilon $ $\}$ and B:$\{$ $1$ $\}$

$A^*= \{\epsilon \}$ and $B^*=\{\epsilon,1,11,111,....\}$

$A \cup B = \{ \epsilon , 1\}$

$A^* \cup B^*= \{\epsilon, 1, 11, 11,111,.....\}$

$(A \cup B)^*=\{\epsilon, 1, 11, 11,111,.....\}$

because lets say $C=(A \cup B)$ and $C=\{ \epsilon,1 \}$, so $C^*=\{\epsilon, 1, 11, 11,111,.....\} $ which is exactly not what I want.

Problem I have is whatever $A \cup B$ outputs, they will get the kleene star outside of the parenthesis which will basically make it the same as the union of kleene stars. Also kleene star will add $\epsilon$ to the resulting languages so I can't trick it by using that. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: Why don't you try $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ instead?

Comment: Yeah, I was too quick to reject that since I didn't check what is inside the $(A \cup B)^* $ properly thinking that it would be the same, I get it now thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=\{a\}, B=\{b\}$ then $ab \in (A \cup B)^\ast$ but $ab \notin A^\ast \cup B^\ast$.

Comment: I tried it but ended up rejecting it quickly thinking that $\{ a, b \}^* $ wouldn't have the strings such as $\{ ab, aab, aaaab, ..., abb, abbb,....,a^nb^n\}$ for n>$0$ but now after seeing your answer I immediately realized I should have checked what is in the set. Thank you.

Comment: @afb $L^\ast$ contains all strings from the alphabet $L$ which in this case also contains $abababab$ etc.